Get the exact value in array
I have a virtual array table as follows.  It is generated from query, not from the cell:



Col1
Col2
Col3




A
E
F


Q
B
N


***
***
***


T
Y
I


R
H
J


W
X
M


***
***
***


G
L
K


A
O
P


***
***
***



I would like to concatenate the value of Col2 between each "***" and use the concatenated value to lookup for the final value.  Here is my anticipated result.
Anticipated Result



Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4




A
E
F
APPLE


Q
B
N



***
***
***



T
Y
I
ORANGE


R
H
J



W
X
M



***
***
***



G
L
K
BANANA


A
O
P



***
***
***




Lookup Table of Col2 to Col4



ColX
ColY




EB
APPLE


YHX
ORANGE


LO
BANANA



What I tried
I tried to search for offset function.  But I don't know how to handle the "cell_reference" in offset function, because the array table is virtually created by query.  I also have difficulties in running the vlookup function through an virtually created array table.
Thanks for helping.

Here's a possible solution:
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(
  data_,A2:C11,
  lkup,E2:F4,
  data,IFNA(VSTACK(,data_)),
  s,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
  R,LAMBDA(a,SORT(a,s,)),
  int,SCAN(,INDEX(data,,2),LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c="***",,a&c))),
  cln,IF(QUERY({int;""},"offset 1",)<>"",,int),
  fll,R(SCAN(,R(cln),LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c="",a,c)))),
  col4_,TOCOL(IF(COUNTIFS(fll,fll,s,"<"&s),,VLOOKUP(fll,lkup,2,0)),2),
  HSTACK(data_,col4_)))

Replace A2:C11 with the formula generating the initial table and E2:F4 with the range containing the lookup table.

Thanks, it works.  I want to know how these two parts work together, would you kindly please explain more?  Thanks.
...
R,LAMBDA(a,SORT(a,s,))
...
fll,R(SCAN(,R(cln),LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c="",a,c))))

I managed to go through the code, thanks.
